# Sending text via TCP

Tags: java, c#, android, tcp, client-server

I want to send a message "Next" from the client (Java) to the server (C #) via TCP. Unfortunately, the data don't come. On the client side first I receive data from the server (it works properly) and then want to send at the same socket, message.

Code fragments:

**SERVER**

```
        public void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        socket.BeginReceive(messageBuffer,0,messageBuffer.Length,SocketFlags.None,ReceiveCallback,null);
    }

    void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int rec = socket.EndReceive(ar);
            string Message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageBuffer, 0, rec);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("SEND ERROR\n{0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**CLIENT**

```
Printwriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        String toSend = "Next";
        out.print(toSend);
```

Comment: Can you show full code of connection initialization, and first send/receive on both sides

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `autoFlush` on the client

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```